# How to create a div "distorsion" with CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to create this kind of arrow and I don't know how to do that correctly...
It should be 100% width pointing down at the middle and with a gradient background...

So far I tried the border solution:

```
.arrow {
    border-top: 5px solid linear-gradient(135deg, #26B7A7, #3BB2B8);
    border-left: 50vw solid transparent;
    border-right: 50vw solid transparent;
    margin: 0 -15px;
    width: auto;
    height: 0px;
}
```

But unfortunately the gradient here doesn't work... So I tried other trick found on internet using `border-image` but without success...

Can you suggest me a way? [Playground here](https://jsfiddle.net/bvnkw6xy/3/)

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Your fiddle looks a lot like the image provided, what is different?

Comment: Use     border-top: 13px solid red; on the arrow

Comment: the gradient is different...

Comment: _“But unfortunately the gradient here doesn't work”_ - that’s because a gradient is not a color, but actually an “image”. That’s why you can use them f.e. as background-image, but they won’t work anywhere where a color is expected.

Answer (score 0):

just add second arrow. And just customize css.

Here example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="arrow"></div>
   <div class="arrow2"></div>
</div>

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #18BB9B, #3AB2B7);
  min-height: 300px;
}

.arrow {
  border-top: 10px solid red;
  border-left: 0vw solid transparent;
  border-right: 0vw solid transparent;
  margin: 0 -10px;
  width: auto;

}
.arrow2 {
  border-top: 10px solid red;
  border-left: 50vw solid transparent;
  border-right: 50vw solid transparent;
  margin: 0 -10px;
  width: auto;

}
```

Comment: This is with a solid color... I need to emulate the gradient along the arrow.

Answer (score -1):

```css
#example1 {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #2eb5ad;
}
```

```html
<div id="example1">

</div>
```